# Send an Email to Lead using a whatID and saving the activity

Tags: apex, email

We are currently hitting the limitation that prevents sending an email to a lead, when using a whatId (we need for the template) and saving the email as activity.

Our use case is the following:

1. We send an email to a Lead
2. This Lead has potentially a lookup towards an Account
3. We need to add an activity both for the lead and the account to keep track of the email

When we send an email from the account page, the email appears under the account activty and we can click on it and see the body. How can we add a similar Activity by Apex?

Comment: WhoId = Lead and WhatId = Lead.Account__c doesn't work? (In VF email terms, this would be recipientType and RelatedTo, respectively)

Comment: No it doesn't work if you want to save the activity